# Internet Explorer Compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have the code below (html, javascript, css) embedded on a website, and although it is working properly at any version (of the -many- last) of firefox and chrome, it is not working properly at internet explorer 9 or older.

**By not working properly i mean that links are not working (no navigation).** sorry i wasnt clear enough...
is there anything wrong or missing from my code? Can i add something?
i tryed to add that meta tag between

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

but nothing happened.

my code is that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{font-family:verdana; font-size:25px}
table{font-size:80%;background:181919}
a{color:white;text-decoration:none;font:bold }
a:hover{color:#009ED8}
td.menu{background:#181919}
table.menu
{

font-size:100%;
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
}
</style>
<script>
function showmenu(elmnt)
{
document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="visible";
}
function hidemenu(elmnt)
{
document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<table width="100%" border = 0>
 <tr bgcolor="181919" >
  <td onmouseover="showmenu('home')" onmouseout="hidemenu('home')" width="15%">
   <a href="http://www.test.com" target=_top>Αρχική</a><br>

  </td>

<td onmouseover="showmenu('company')" onmouseout="hidemenu('company')" width="25%">
   <a href=" http://www.test.com" target=_top>Η εταιρία μας</a><br>
  </td>
  <td onmouseover="showmenu('properties')" onmouseout="hidemenu('properties')" width="20%">
   <a href=" http://www.test.com" target=_top>Ακίνητα</a><br>
   <table class="menu" id="properties" width="120">
<tr><td><br></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href=" http://www.test.com" target=_top>Πώληση</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href=" http://www.test.com" target=_top>Ενοικίαση</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href=" http://www.test.com" target=_top>Μισθωμένα</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="http://www.test.com" target=_top>Υπό κατασκευή</a></td></tr>

   </table>
  </td>
  <td onmouseover="showmenu('contact')" onmouseout="hidemenu('contact')" width="20%">
   <a href=" http://www.test.com" target=_top>Επικοινωνία</a><br>
   <table class="menu" id="contact" width="120">


   </table>
</td>
  <td onmouseover="showmenu('press')" onmouseout="hidemenu('press')" width="20%">
 <a href=" http://www.test.com" target=_top>Γραφείο Τύπου</a><br>
   <table class="menu" id="press" width="120">
<tr><td><br></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="http://www.test.com" target=_top>Ανακοινώσεις</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href=" http://www.test.com" target=_top>Οικονομικά Στοιχεία</a></td></tr>


   </table>
  </td>

 </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, "not working"?  Not working *how*? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: What do you mean, not working properly? What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: _"not working properly"_ - Please explain what you mean by "properly". That is, add an explanation of the desired behaviour and the actual behaviour. (By the way, where are the `'home'` & `'company'` elements that you are trying to show and hide? There are corresponding elements for the other mouseovers, but not for those two.)

Comment: have you looked in the dev tools to see if you're getting an errors? did you see anything there?

Comment: i dont get any errors...

Comment: I put it in a jsfiddle, and it seems to be working just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/PVUBd/5/

Comment: `target=_top ` should be `target="_top"`. Sounds like something that would break IE

Comment: I also put it into a fiddle and the links navigate fine: http://jsfiddle.net/shayl/bXKqk/1/

However, in IE9 the heights of the cells are shorter, that's the only thing that is different for me.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 or older are not fully support latest html5 tags . it's better to use chrome for html5 .

Comment: IE8 is worse, but there are js plugins out there that give them compatibility like html5shiv